# How can we restore deleted Organization Unit or OU in windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, restore, organizational-unit

I deleted one of the Organization Unit from my windows server 2012r2,but now i want to restore it how i can i restore it,is it possible through LDP or something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you enabled AD Recycle Bin before, you can restore the OU first, then all the objects. [Here is a step by step tutorial](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/08/27/the-ad-recycle-bin-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/).

Basically, you need to restore the OU:

```
Get-ADObject -filter 'msds-lastKnownRdn -eq "MyOUName" -and lastKnownParent -eq "DC=MyDomain,DC=com"' -includeDeletedObjects | Restore-ADObject
```

And then the objects:

```
Get-ADObject -filter 'lastKnownParent -eq "OU=MyOUName,DC=MyDomain,DC=com"' -includeDeletedObjects | restore-adobject
```

If AD Recycle Bin wasn't enabled, you have to restore from a backup.